# Install White listing for TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

My network is extremely locked down for Servers and I need to find out what the install package for TFS 2017 connects to so that i can get those white listed to complete the install.  Does anyone have a listing of sites that the install package reaches out to to complete the install?

Comment: Never checked this, it's more depend on what you have installed on your computer if you are using a web installer for the installation. Because some dependencies maybe installed with other software...  Suggest you download the standalone on-premise TFS image (iso file) and install locally.